# CSS that can be reproduced beautifully in Chrome is dirty in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, background-color

When applying the following CSS
Chrome and Chromium-derived browsers (including OPERA) can reflect the diamond pattern beautifully, but if you apply this to Firefox and its derivative browsers, it will look dirty.

If you want to reproduce a beautiful diamond pattern etc. in Firefox, how can you fix it?

Page to actually insert CSS
https://www.yahoo.co.jp/

```
/* Base element */
body{
background-color: #ff3838e3;
color: #0d0d0d;
filter: sepia(30%);
zoom: 95.5%;}
*:not(.barGraph){
font-family: "Meiryo", sans-serif !important;
font-size: 16px;
border-width: 0.1px !important;
border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Code for problems with Firefox and Firefox-derived browsers ↓ */

div#wrapper._1DyDVN-3FsqGF_QKLg1M9G{
background-color: #ff151500;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, #ffe5e545), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, #ffe5e545), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #ffe5e545)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #ffe5e545));
-webkit-background-size:200px 200px;
}
```

### I try to keep it to a minimum,Further scraped the above The "minimum required" code is:

```
/* Code for problems with Firefox and Firefox-derived browsers ↓ */

body{
background-color: #ff3838e3;
}

div#wrapper._1DyDVN-3FsqGF_QKLg1M9G{
background-color: #ff151500;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, #ffe5e545), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, #ffe5e545), color-stop(.25, transparent), to(transparent)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #ffe5e545)),
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.75, transparent), color-stop(.75, #ffe5e545));
-webkit-background-size:200px 200px;
}
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: Target page is yahoo?

Comment: Yes, the target page is Yahoo !, but it is not the American version but the Japanese version.

The reason for the link is to make it easier for others to understand the situation.

Comment: What dos that mean? target page???

Comment: Isn't it transmitted even in the "edit page where you actually insert CSS"?

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.